# Public folder image in my React Header component only displays on my Index page

Tags: image, reactjs

I've made a Header component which is loaded into all of my view containers. Inside the component is an image taken from my public folder:

```
<img className="book col-md-1" src="./image/book_icon_512.png" placeholder="book icon"/>
```

My main App component displays this image, but my other components that render the Header component do not.

I'm using react-router, and the component that works is my "/" index page. The rest of the views use other routes. Could this have something to do with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.`(dot) in the src path. The says that the path is relative to the current one.

```
<img className="book col-md-1" src="/image/book_icon_512.png" placeholder="book icon"/>
```